# custom domain on heroku not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I added heroku custom domain:

> heroku domains:add *.phuhao.com

But it's only worked with www.phuhao.com not work with phuhao.com. please help me solved this problem. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to map phuhao.com seperately. It will not map *.phuhao.com.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains has the info; check the section on naked domains.